# SSRS- Reporting Service Configuration: Make link (included on email subscriptions) point to website, not internal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Instead of it saying "SQL-DEV1", I want to replace it with my application name:  Like app.myapp.com/Reports?id=myreportnamehere

Can someone tell me what to change and where to change it?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-report-server-urls-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017) and related links within and you should be able to figure out where to change it.

Comment: I want to configure it for application use.